# Django admin - передача имени редактора, как контекстного параметра

Tags: python, django, django-admin, backend

Я занимаюсь разработкой проекта на Django, и мне захотелось провернуть одну штуку.
Есть модель поста

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class BGD(models.Model):
    isvisible = models.BooleanField('Видим ли блок')
    isspoiler = models.BooleanField('Спрятан ли блок в спойлер')
    spoilertext = models.CharField('Текст спойлера', max_length = 100, blank = True)
    priority = models.IntegerField('Приоритет отображения')
    caption = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length = 127)
    cont = models.TextField('Содержимое')
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.priority) + ' | ' + self.caption
    def isRecent(self):
        return self.pubdate >= (timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days = 7))
    def visibility(self):
        return self.pubdate < timezone.now() and self.isvisible
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'БДЖ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'БЖД'
```

Есть вьюшка, которая открывает шаблон страницы, передавая эту модель (модель BGD) как контекстный

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def bgd(request):
    content_list = BGD.objects.order_by('priority')
    return render(request, 'wiki/БЖД.html', {'content_list':content_list})
```

В админке же при просмотре модели есть кнопка История, которая позволяет смотреть, кто последний менял модель, когда менял и что именно менял
[image: История изменения]
Каким образом можно передавать имя и фамилию последнего редактора сообщения, как контекстный параметр? Как вычленить их из таблицы БД **django_admin_log**?

Желательно, чтобы решение могло находиться в подобном виде:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
/* импорт откуда-то модели логов */

def bgd(request):
    content_list = BGD.objects.order_by('priority')
    last_editor = /* ??? */
    return render(request, 'wiki/БЖД.html', {'content_list':content_list, 'last_editor':last_editor})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что будет архитектурной ошибкой пытаться получить данные автора из логов. Логи как раз таки ведутся на основе тех манипуляций с данными, которые вы описываете в коде, логи нужны для чтения результатов работы кода, а не получения данных обеспечивающих работу кода.

Вместо этого, лучше добавьте поле автора в вашу модель `BGD` и заполняйте значение, получая данные пользователя из `request` каждый раз, при успешной валидации данных.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Так как редактирование производится через админку, то должно сработать это:

```
### models.py

from django.conf import settings

class BGD(models.Model):
   ...
   last_editor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE, ...)
   ...
```

```
### admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

class BGDAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.last_editor = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Как в таком случае можно реализовать в модели поле автора, в которое автоматически будет помещаться имя последнего редактора? Ведь запросы создания и изменения моделей также обрабатывает `djago.cintrib.admin`

Comment: @Евгений, редактирование производится через админку?

Comment: Да, редактирование производится через админку