# Django. Выполнение функции при добавлении модели

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Задача такая: есть файл excel, который ежемесячно необходимо загружать и данные из этого файла должны перетекать в модельку X.

Как я увидел решение: я создал отдельную модель с одним полем FileField, туда загружается Excel. Затем, добавил кнопку в админку, по которой последний файл обрабатывался и добавлял новые записи в Х.

Вопрос: где-то интуитивно я понимаю, что это похоже на самодел и должен быть метод, позволяющий при загрузке этого Excel-файла автоматически выполнять какую-то другую функцию.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете объявить необходимые при сохранении модели действия

```
# admin.py

from .models import ModelName
from django.contrib import admin

class SaveData(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass # вместо pass то, что нужно делать, когда модель сохраняется черед админку
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(ModelName, SaveData)
```

При сохранении данных через админку Django будет вызываться метод `save_model` указанного дочернего для `ModelAdmin` класса (в данном случае - `SaveData`)

Это также можно оформить с использованием декоратора:

```
# admin.py

from .models import ModelName
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(ModelName)
class SaveData(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass # вместо pass то, что нужно делать, когда модель сохраняется черед админку
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

[Исходный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1052486/361777)