# Python. Django. Problem encoding xlsx file

Tags: python, django, utf-8, кодировка

Всем доброго времени суток!
Только разобрался с тем, как решить этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120630/django-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) (возможно, я точно не знаю, это может быть связано с моим текущим вопросом), как появилась следующая ошибка...

Долго пытался по-разному обработать xslx файл. Одна из версий:

admin.py

```
class AddScheduleItems(admin.ModelAdmin):

def parse_file(self, csv_upload):
    file = csv_upload.read().decode('utf-8')
    csv_data = csv.reader(StringIO(file))
    for row in csv_data:
        print(row)

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    self.parse_file(obj.file)
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Трейс:

---

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1645, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1529, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1572, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Projects\dr\hram\schedule\admin.py", line 34, in save_model
    self.parse_file(obj.file)
  File "C:\Projects\dr\hram\schedule\admin.py", line 28, in parse_file
    file = csv_upload.read().decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 16: invalid start byte
```

Я пробовал много разных вариаций, пробовал и другие кодировки, но все время во что-то упирался.

Ошибка для 'ascii':

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Ошибка для 'cp437' и 'ISO-8859-1':

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1645, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1529, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1572, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Projects\dr\hram\schedule\admin.py", line 34, in save_model
    self.parse_file(obj.file)
  File "C:\Projects\dr\hram\schedule\admin.py", line 30, in parse_file
    for row in csv_data:
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

Ошибка для 'windows-1251':

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 596: character maps to <undefined>
```

В связи с этим, у меня возникло стойкое ощущение, что я просто неправильно обрабатываю xlsx файлы средствами Django или Питона, но где именно понять не могу.

Буду максимально благодарен за подсказ!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем и целом, подвела моя внимательность и соображалка. Я пытался обработать xlsx файл библиотекой csv... Поменял на openpyxl и все заработало.